# httpd Server slows down, Then Goes unresponsive

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, php5

Well, I recently switched over to Centos 6 from Windows, and Installed httpd php ispconfig 3, and mail server stuff.

But after some hours (around 5-8), The server gets slow, and the websites does not load anymore, And when connecting with ssh, It takes like forever until i can login.

Also, I noticed the HDD Light is always lit when it happends.

I am using ISPConfig 3 for cpanel, and Apache2 for web server.

I have even reinstalled the OS 1 time, And it still happends...

Apache Config

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       10
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   50
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  40000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

#
# The following modules are not loaded by default:
#
#LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#

#
# Load config files from the config directory "/etc/httpd/conf.d".
#
Include conf.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin tek@teknikk.info


#ServerName www.example.com:80

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    UserDir disabled

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    # 
    #UserDir public_html

</IfModule>

#
# Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
#
#<Directory /home/*/public_html>
#    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
#    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from all
#    </Limit>
#    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
#        Order deny,allow
#        Deny from all
#    </LimitExcept>
#</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
# The index.html.var file (a type-map) is used to deliver content-
# negotiated documents.  The MultiViews Option can be used for the 
# same purpose, but it is much slower.
#
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

#
# TypesConfig describes where the mime.types file (or equivalent) is
# to be found.
#
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

DefaultType text/plain

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
#   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

#
# EnableMMAP: Control whether memory-mapping is used to deliver
# files (assuming that the underlying OS supports it).
# The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted 
# filesystems.  On some systems, turning it off (regardless of
# filesystem) can improve performance; for details, please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablemmap
#
#EnableMMAP off

#
# EnableSendfile: Control whether the sendfile kernel support is 
# used to deliver files (assuming that the OS supports it). 
# The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted 
# filesystems.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile
#
#EnableSendfile off

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog logs/error_log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# "combinedio" includes actual counts of actual bytes received (%I) and sent (%O); this
# requires the mod_logio module to be loaded.
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

#
# The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
# If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
# container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
# define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
# logged therein and *not* in this file.
#
#CustomLog logs/access_log common

#
# If you would like to have separate agent and referer logfiles, uncomment
# the following directives.
#
#CustomLog logs/referer_log referer
#CustomLog logs/agent_log agent

#
# For a single logfile with access, agent, and referer information
# (Combined Logfile Format), use the following directive:
#
CustomLog logs/access_log combined

#
# Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
# name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP directory
# listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI generated
# documents or custom error documents).
# Set to "EMail" to also include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
# Set to one of:  On | Off | EMail
#
ServerSignature On

#
# Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is 
# Alias fakename realname
#
# Note that if you include a trailing / on fakename then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  So "/icons" isn't aliased in this
# example, only "/icons/".  If the fakename is slash-terminated, then the 
# realname must also be slash terminated, and if the fakename omits the 
# trailing slash, the realname must also omit it.
#
# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If you
# do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
#
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# WebDAV module configuration section.
# 
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

#
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the realname directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the client.
# The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias directives as to
# Alias.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# Redirect allows you to tell clients about documents which used to exist in
# your server's namespace, but do not anymore. This allows you to tell the
# clients where to look for the relocated document.
# Example:
# Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

#
# Directives controlling the display of server-generated directory listings.
#

#
# IndexOptions: Controls the appearance of server-generated directory
# listings.
#
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

#
# AddIcon* directives tell the server which icon to show for different
# files or filename extensions.  These are only displayed for
# FancyIndexed directories.
#
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

#
# DefaultIcon is which icon to show for files which do not have an icon
# explicitly set.
#
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif

#
# AddDescription allows you to place a short description after a file in
# server-generated indexes.  These are only displayed for FancyIndexed
# directories.
# Format: AddDescription "description" filename
#
#AddDescription "GZIP compressed document" .gz
#AddDescription "tar archive" .tar
#AddDescription "GZIP compressed tar archive" .tgz

#
# ReadmeName is the name of the README file the server will look for by
# default, and append to directory listings.
#
# HeaderName is the name of a file which should be prepended to
# directory indexes. 
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

#
# IndexIgnore is a set of filenames which directory indexing should ignore
# and not include in the listing.  Shell-style wildcarding is permitted.
#
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t


AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw


LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW


ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


#AddType application/x-tar .tgz


#AddEncoding x-compress .Z
#AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl


#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

#AddHandler send-as-is asis


AddHandler type-map var


AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml


Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

#    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully



NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Include /etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/
```

Apache error_log (from around where it crashed)

```
[Tue Jan 29 03:18:07 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.7 PHP/5.3.3 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 29 15:21:08 2013] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
[Tue Jan 29 15:27:08 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5925 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:27:20 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 2041 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:28:32 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5185 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:31:08 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5729 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:31:45 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6122 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:34:39 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5795 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:34:47 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5845 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:34:51 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5868 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:35:28 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5731 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:35:44 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5863 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:36:24 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6030 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:36:32 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5785 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:36:40 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6072 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:37:43 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5670 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:37:55 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6134 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:38:43 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5843 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:38:47 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6023 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:39:35 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6059 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:40:20 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5700 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:40:24 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6162 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:40:28 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6988 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:40:32 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6112 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:40:32 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5996 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:41:40 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5740 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:42:20 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 7741 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:42:36 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 7547 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:08 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5747 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:08 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6054 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:12 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6108 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:12 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5074 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:28 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6116 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:52 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 6046 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:52 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5854 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:56 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 7005 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:44:04 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5884 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:44:12 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5668 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:44:21 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 5725 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Teknikk.info' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Teknikk.info' does NOT match server name!?
[Tue Jan 29 15:46:23 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.7 PHP/5.3.3 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 29 15:55:35 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 29 15:55:36 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Jan 29 15:55:36 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

Server Specs
CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 2.66MHz
RAM: 4 GB DDR3 1333
HDD1: 60 GB SSD
HDD2: 2 TB HDD
HDD3: 500 GB HDD
RAID: HDD1 + HDD2 = RAID 1 (Motherboard raid)

It's getting annoying that the sites goes unresponsive/down for no reason.
When I used Windows IIS 7.5, It was much stable, Just that it spammed the process list with php-cgi.exe with alot of processes.
So, How can it be fixed? Or any more logs?
I currenty have around 5 sites installed, One comminity hosted for someone using Socialengine 4, and rest is mine (VirtualHosts).

Comment: Try setting `Keepalive Off` and see how that goes

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says you reached your `MaxClients` setting. If it's still at the default of 256, try doubling it to 512 (in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`). You'll also need to raise the `ServerLimits` to the same thing. Install some monitoring software (like Munin) and turn enable `/server-status` in apache so you can keep an eye on your connection numbers.

I've seen the exact same behavior before and it was caused by hitting the MaxClients value. Raising it solved the problem for us.

Comment: Should also check for processes limit on OS? Sometimes, tuning values related to the number of threads/simultaneous requests handled, it happens to be the case.

Comment: Yes, which also happened to me :) Good suggestion. Teknikk, these can be found at `/etc/security/limits.conf` or with the `ulimit` command.

Comment: Ok, I have raised the settings, So I will see if it gets better now.

Comment: Did that fix the issue for you?